# Opening systems that enable strong tactics

Tags: opening

First off I'm not looking for a gimmick / trap, but rather I'm looking for a new opening system for white / black that could enable more tactical options.

For the last year or so I've been playing the Open Scillian as Black, and the Queens Gambit as white, but I did that because they are very common systems. Now I am interested in finding systems that lead to open boards so that I can start playing my 'style of chess'.

Obviously I'm not the only one influencing the board, but I would love to learn how to create more opportunities for smothered mates in particular. Any suggestions?

Here is a [link](https://lichess.org/@/Nebri) to my lichess.org profile.

Comment: I wouldn't really say the Queen's Gambit and Open Sicilian are similar.